# Hot set the /Source (or /Dest) to storage emulator for AzCopy

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator, azcopy

I want to dump some simple tables to my local machine's emulator so that i can test my app locally first. i am able to azcopy to my local disk as files. but i can not find how to specify /Dest for storage emulator. can someone help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far AzCopy doesn't support copying table to table directly. To work around it, you can run two commands to firstly export the source table to local, and then import back to the target table.

> AzCopy.exe /Source:https://youraccount1.table.core.windows.net/srctable /SourceKey:key1 /Dest:D:\LocalFolder /Manifest:yourfilename /SplitSize:128
>
> AzCopy.exe /Source:D:\LocalFolder /Dest:http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/desttable /DestType:Table /DestKey:key2 /Manifest:yourfilename /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace

Comment: @ZhZhaoxing Lu - Microsoft . Thanks for your answer. I want to copy tables, overall, your answer seems right. but seems not accurate.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/  seems has answer. I need to provide Desk: as "http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1"(very strange, Ms expose hardcode string here!!it is not the first time Ms expose these unprofessional name!) and the Account key need be hardcode to :"Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==" also, as you claimed I need specify DestType:Table. Shame on Ms to have this miracle hardcode and not defined in code!

Comment: Note - the latest release of azcopy (v10 currently) no longer supports table storage - previous version with support is still available for download (v7.3) - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-with-table-support-v73